# SKElement - Create x y scrollbar for image

Tags: c#, wpf, skiasharp

I am a bit new to WPF. I wanted to make my image scrollable when I scale up the image. This is my XAML code.

```
<UserControl xmlns: skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.WPF:assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.WPF">
  <Grid> 
    <skia:SKElement Name="Canvas" PaintSurface="SKElement_PaintSurface">
  </Grid>
</UserControl>

private void SKElement_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
   \\Code goes here...
}
```

Inside the SKElement_PaintSurface method, I created a way to draw the bitmap image on the canvas. But when I scale up the image I can't scroll the image. Does anyone know to create a scrollbar for this?

Comment: Have you looked at `ScrollViewer`? [ScrollViewer Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/scrollviewer-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: I checked. But i dont know how to apply it.

Comment: The link in my previous comment should get you started with that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `Canvas` in a `ScrollViewer` element and set its `Height` and/or `Width` when you scale it:

```
    <UserControl xmlns: skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.WPF:assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.WPF">
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <skia:SKElement Name="DrawCanvas" PaintSurface="SKElement_PaintSurface">
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

---

```
private void SKElement_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    \\Code goes here...

    DrawCanvas.Height = 100;
}
```

Comment: Be careful - canvas size is limited by system - ranges from 4096x4096 to 16384x16384. If you want to scroll bigger images - you should implement scrolling within canvas - redraw viewport.